# Nested case statement in sql for date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong. What I'm trying to do is get the half of each month, lets say if i input 8/1/2015 it should return 7/16/2015 and if i used 8/31/2015 it should return 8/15/2015. I created a Sql Script which is isn't running, here is the code.

```
SELECT case when @rank = 'R' 
then month(DATEADD(day, -15, @date_from)+'/'+ 
case when day(DATEADD(day, -15, @date_from)) between 1 and 15 then 1 else 16 end
+'/'+year(DATEADD(day, -15, @date_from) 
DATEADD(month, -1, @date_from)
end
```

but i get a error, is there a way for me to do this more efficiently? and what is my solution for the error?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: While editing your question, I noticed that the parentheses don't seem to line up.  Can you edit your question to fix this?

Comment: I guess you are missing the `ELSE` for the outer CASE for rank other than R. And you are trying to concat with `char` and `int` makes error

Comment: is it not possible to create a date out of concatenated strings sir? if you may, is there a better way sir for my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an invalid statement as it is missing a few brackets, and it maybe missing an else statement for the first case when. I am unsure if this is what you are trying to achieve.

```sql
DECLARE @rank AS VARCHAR(50) = 'R';
DECLARE @date_from AS DATETIME = '1/1/2015';

SELECT  CASE WHEN @rank = 'R'
        THEN
            CAST(
            -- get month
            Cast(Month(Dateadd( day, -15, @date_from )) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + 
            -- get day
            CASE WHEN Day(Dateadd( day, -15, @date_from )) BETWEEN 1 AND 15 THEN '1' ELSE '16' END + '/' + 
            -- get year
            Cast(Year(Dateadd( day, -15, @date_from )) AS VARCHAR(5)) AS DATETIME)
        ELSE
            DATEADD(month, -1, @date_from)
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a subquery sir, the complete code looks like this

```
set @refdatefrom = 
(
SELECT case when @rank = 'R' 
then month(DATEADD(day, -15, @date_from)+'/'+ 
case when day(DATEADD(day, -15, @date_from)) between 1 and 15 then 1 else 16 end
+'/'+year(DATEADD(day, -15, @date_from) 
DATEADD(month, -1, @date_from)
end
)
```

then each value which i would add will be inserted in a table. The error which i get is

```
Server: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure finalize, Line 65
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'end'.
Server: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure finalize, Line 107
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'end'.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @date DATE = '8/15/2015'

SELECT  CASE 
             WHEN DAY(@date) <= 15 AND @rank = 'R'  
            THEN  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @date) -1, 0) + 14 
             WHEN DAY(@date) > 15 AND @rank = 'R' 
            THEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @date), 0) + 14
        END
```

You would assign value to your variable something like this...

```
SELECT @refdatefrom =  CASE 
                             WHEN DAY(@date) <= 15 AND @rank = 'R'  
                            THEN  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @date) -1, 0) + 14 
                             WHEN DAY(@date) > 15 AND @rank = 'R' 
                            THEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @date), 0) + 14
                        END
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatching parentheses on your code. Try this to clean it up:

```
SELECT 
    case
        when @rank = 'R' 
            then month(DATEADD(day, -15, @date_from)) + '/' + 
                case 
                    when day(DATEADD(day, -15, @date_from)) between 1 and 15 then 1 
                    else 16 
                end
            + '/' + year(DATEADD(day, -15, @date_from))
        else DATEADD(month, -1, @date_from)
    end
```

However, this will still produce an error saying:

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

To fix the above error, you need to convert your `ints` to `varchar` and convert the `else` part to `varchar`:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN @rank = 'R' 
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MONTH(DATEADD(DAY, -15, @date_from))) + '/' + 
                CASE 
                    WHEN DAY(DATEADD(DAY, -15, @date_from)) BETWEEN 1 AND 15 THEN '1'
                    ELSE '16'
                END
            + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, -15, @date_from)))
        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @date_from), 101)
    END
```

---

An alternative solution without using sting concatenation would be:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN DAY(@date_from) < 15 THEN
            DATEADD(D, 15, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @date_from) - 1, 0))
        ELSE
            DATEADD(D, 15, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @date_from), 0))
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following does what you want:

- Subtract 15 days from the date.  What you want is the 15th of the month for this date.
- So, subtract the day of the month from the date.  This is the last day of the previous month.
- Add (1 + 15days) to get the 15th.

This turns into a SQL statement with no `case` and no strings:

```
select datediff(day,
                16 - day(datediff(day, -15, @date_from)),
                datediff(day, -15, @date_from)
               )
```